# Cannot install PyEOS using pip

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am having trouble installing pyEOS using pip on my MacBook M2 running MacOS Ventura 13.4.1. How to successfully install pyEOS on this system?

```
pip install pyEOS      
Collecting pyEOS
  Using cached pyEOS-0.63.tar.gz (4.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/8w/15bkc1tn7ksbbt1ntnh14r7c0000gq/T/pip-install-md5ukh5r/pyeos_a42e8f309446444dbfb0599c8bb85cde/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
          from pip.req import parse_requirements
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

The last release `pyEOS` 0.63 [was released](https://pypi.org/project/pyEOS/0.63/) at Jun 16, 2015. [The Github repository](https://github.com/spotify/pyeos/) was archived on Jul 15, 2019 and is now read-only.

The project seems to be abandoned and outdated; it requires [very old `pip`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/9.0.3/pip/req).

To install `pyEOS` you need Python 2.7 and `pip` 9.0.3.